# Why is my program sending the information to a page that doesn't exist?

Tags: php, http-status-code-404

I'm working on a small project using PHP. There are various pages carrying over user information. Right now, I'm trying to get user entered topics to carry over to a separate page called topics.php using these functions:

```
function dispsubcategories($parent_id){
    include ('../db.php');
    $select = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT cat_id, subcat_id, 
    subcategory_title, subcategory_descr FROM categories, subcategories
                                 WHERE ($parent_id = categories.cat_id) 
                                 AND ($parent_id = subcategories.parent_id)");
    echo "<tr><th width='90%'>Categories</th><th width='10%'>Topics</th></tr>";

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select)){
       echo "<tr><td class='category_title'><a href='topics.php".$row['cat_id']."/".$row['subcat_id']."'>
                ".$row['subcategory_title']."<br/>";
       echo $row['subcategory_descr']."</a></td>";
       echo "<td class='num-topics'>".getnumtopics($parent_id, $row['subcat_id'])."</td></tr>";
    }
}

//Displays categories
function getnumtopics($cat_id, $subcat_id){
    include ('../db.php');
    $select = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT category_id, subcategory_id FROM 
                           topics WHERE ".$cat_id." = category_id
                           AND ".$subcat_id." = subcategory_id");
    $get = mysqli_num_rows($select);

    return $get;
}


//Displays Topics Within categories
function disptopics($cid, $scid){
    include ('../db.php');
    $select = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT topic_id, author, title, 
                                     date_posted, views, replies 
                                     FROM categories, subcategories, topics
                                     WHERE ($cid = topics.category_id) AND 
                                     ($scid = topics.subcategory_id) AND 
                                     ($cid = categories.cat_id) AND 
                                     ($scid = subcategories.subcat_id) 
                                     ORDER BY topic_id DESC");
}
```

Sorry about the indentation, entering it into SO messed it up a bit.

Anyway, from this, you can see my functions is saying to send the user to topics.php when a category is clicked, but for whatever reason, when I click a category, the file path says this at the top of the screen:

[image]

It's being sent to topics1.php and I keep getting a 404 error. I don't have that file listed anywhere in my code as far as I can tell, but there's so much of it I can't tell if I'm missing something.

Can anyone spot the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I can see you`re missing a slash after

```
 <a href='topics.php
```

so try this

```
<a href='topics.php/".$row['cat_id']."/".$row['subcat_id']."'>
            ".$row['subcategory_title']."<br/>";
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I keep missing such little errors, do you know of any techniques to keep track of hundreds of lines of code?

Comment: Well you could use https://phpcodechecker.com/ but it doesn't work always. I beleive you already know about editors like sublime, but however if you don't, these editors changes the text color based on its philosophy, for example variables have different colors with statements, etc!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, right now I'm using Atom, which works pretty similarly. I'm going to research if there are text editors that notify you about errors like Eclipse does for Java.

Comment: @CaptainAmerica16, already it's too hard to know the logic problems! Because as you had the problem on the above question, there's no application which would tell you the error. All what checkers can do is to tell you about syntax errors! However if you find any, feel free to share it!

Comment: I don't mean to bother you, so don't feel obliged to answer, but where you able to spot anything else wrong with the code I posted?

Comment: @CaptainAmerica16 make sure you are using mysqli_real_escape_string otherwise it can be injected. Read more articles about SQLi Injection!